# Axios GET Request won't execute in a while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop, axios, geocoding

When I run `node index.js` with this code, everything works appropriately. What it's doing is getting a random coordinate with the randomGeo function and then converting that into an address with the Axios call. Lastly, this transPredtoJSON function is called in the .then of the Axios call, which takes the address and adds it to a JSON file.  The problem arises when I want to execute this more than once, which I'll show in the next code snippet.

```
randomCoordinate = randomGeo({ latitude: originlat, longitude: originlng }, radius)

lat = randomCoordinate.latitude
lng = randomCoordinate.longitude
reverseGeoCodeURL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${GEOCODE_API_KEY}`

// get closest address to the coordinate
axios.get(reverseGeoCodeURL).then(res => {
    let ranAddr = res.data.results[0].formatted_address
    let correctCity = /, Southlake,/i

    if (correctCity.exec(ranAddr)) { // only Southlake addresses
        transPredtoJSON(ranAddr) // are added to the output json file
    }
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('error: ', error);
})
```

Below I'm wrapping the above code in a while loop. I'll have a counter that will keep track of how many addresses were added to the output file and stop when it reaches its limit. Besides, axios.get never gets called bc the console log only outputs `count: 0` infinitely.  The weird thing is, when I move `count += 1` right after the axios call so that the count increments whether or not the address is added, axios.get gets called and adds the addresses to the file like it's supposed to. Why doesn't Axios run in this while loop?

```
let enoughAddresses = 10
let count = 0

while (count < enoughAddresses) {
    console.log('count', count);
    
    randomCoordinate = randomGeo({ latitude: originlat, longitude: originlng }, radius)

    lat = randomCoordinate.latitude
    lng = randomCoordinate.longitude
    reverseGeoCodeURL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${lng}&key=${key}`
    
    axios.get(reverseGeoCodeURL).then(res => {
        console.log('inside axios .then');
        
        let ranAddr = res.data.results[0].formatted_address
        let corrCity = /, Southlake,/i

        if (corrCity.exec(ranAddr)) {
            transPredtoJSON(ranAddr)
            count += 1 // only increment count when an address has been added
            console.log('count', count);
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('error: ', error);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the axios function is running async.  You can probably use a promise to solve this.

this pseudo code might point you in the right direction:

```js
let enoughAddresses = 10

for (i = 0; i < enoughAddresses; i++) {    
    addresses.push(new Promise((r, j) => {
        // your async function to get addresses
    });
}

// returns a promise when all your async functions are done
Promise.all(addresses).then((values) => {
    // values should contain your addresses
});
```

also, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  I didn't think I'd have an asynchronicity issue because all the logic is in the .then which runs synchronously; but, what's actually happening is that the while loop would loop hundreds of times before axios.get was even called. For the solution, I wrapped the while loop in an async IIFE and awaited the axios call.